# Trigger ~ Atributo Download HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Bom dia pessoal,
Estou com o seguinte impecilho : Preciso fazer o download de alguns arquivos texto (.txt) com o atributo `download` mas preciso fazer isso de forma automática, quando carregue a página ou uma trigger que à ative, o problema é que não sei como ativar o elemento que possui o atributo. Já tentei

`$('.meuElemento').trigger('click');`

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Tenta `$('.meuElemento').click()`

Comment: @JuniorNunes7 Já tentei também, mas ele retorna o elemento "<a>.refDownload"

Comment: Poxa cara que estranho, talvez isso só funcione pra um elemento e não vários, tenta fazer um loop com todos os seus elementos e disparar o evento de um em um.

Comment: @JuniorNunes7 Mas é o que eu quero kkkk, fazer o download dos arquivos um por vez, mas não funcionou nenhuma das maneiras acima.

Comment: Ok, aqui no comentário fica difícil colocar código, vou postar uma resposta com o código e você vê se vai funcionar pra você, se não funcionar eu apago.

Comment: @JuniorNunes7 Tudo bem, agradeço desde já a tentativa de ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu pode fazer o seguinte, entre as tags `a` você pode colocar o texto dentro de um `span` com um identificador(no caso eu coloquei a class download) e usar o código para clicar de um em um, o problema é que o navegador pede permissão pra baixar todos os arquivos de uma vez só.

```
<a href="http://www.petcidade.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/cachorro-tenta-pegar-petisco-imagem-1-reproducao.jpg" download="teste"><span class="download">teste1</span></a>

<script>
    $('.download').trigger('click');
</script>
```

OBS.: O atributo download não funcionou pra esse link, mas pra um arquivo local ele funcionou no teste que eu fiz aqui!

Ou poderia fazer dessa maneira aqui também:

```
$('a').each(function(i, el) {
    window.location = $(el).prop('href');
});
```

Dessa forma você não precisaria colocar a tag `span`, mas não teria o controle pelo atributo `download`.

Comment: Funcionou certinho como preciso, obrigado .

Comment: Na verdade aquele each nem é necessário, você pode deixar somente o `$('.download').trigger('click')` que vai funcionar, vou editar!

Comment: Certo, mas só precisava ativar o elemento mesmo, agora vejo como pode ser melhor aqui no meu caso.